# mysql: Usar LIMIT con LEFT JOIN y COUNT

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join, count, limit

Tengo 3 tablas:

- Tabla `productos`:

  ```
  | id_producto | nombre_producto   |
  | ----------- | ----------------- |
  | 1           | camiseta espinete |
  | 2           | camiseta batman   |
  | 3           | camiseta simpson  |
  ```
- Tabla `usuarios`:

  ```
  | id_usuario | nombre_usuario  |
  | ---------- | --------------- |
  | 1          | jose perez      |
  | 2          | manolo garcia   |
  | 3          | antonio sanchez |
  ```
- Tabla `favoritos`:

  ```
  | id_favoritos | id_producto | id_usuario |
  | ------------ | ----------- | ---------- |
  | 1            | 3           | 2          |
  | 2            | 1           | 3          |
  | 3            | 2           | 1          |
  ```

Donde un usuario puede añadir productos como favoritos. Me interesa listar todos los productos con la cantidad de veces que lo han añadido a favoritos, ordenarlo por dicha cantidad, y limitar el resultado a X productos para realizar después la paginación de los productos. No se como usar de forma correcta LIMIT en esta consulta:

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_favorito
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudar, se lo agradecería muchísimo, un saludo a todos!

Comment: Puede venirte bien esta entrada anterior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset

Comment: Y que problema te da el código que pusiste de ejemplo??

Answer (score 0):

Ya me dieron la solución!

La dejo por aquí por si a alguien le sirve...

En la primera consulta se mostrarían los 10 productos que mas han sido añadidos como favoritos por los usuarios. En la segunda consulta se mostrarían los 10 productos que más gustan contando desde el número 10 en la lista, es decir, del numero 10 al 20.

Los diez productos que más gustan:

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_producto
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Los que más gustan del 10 al 20

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_producto
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```